# How to change the branching point in Git?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

Suppose I have the following structure in my git repo:

```
          C'---D'---E'---F'    (dev)
        / 
A---B---C---D---E---F       (master)
```

I would like to pull `C'` into the master branch and change the branching point to `C'`, i.e., I want to turn the above into

```
              D'---E'---F'     (dev)
             / 
A---B---C---C'---D---E---F  (master)
```

I believe I should use a combination of cherry-picking and rebasing, but I am confused about how to do so exactly.  Which sequence of operations should I perform?

---

***Suggestion*** after comments for a clearer schema (since same-letter commits in the original were in fact unnecessary)

```
          G---H---I---J   (dev)
         / 
A---B---C---D---E---F     (master)
```

with the associated expected result :

```
              H---I---J    (dev)
             / 
A---B---C---G---D---E---F  (master)
```

Comment: What is the relation between same-letter commits? (i.e. `C` and `C'`) Are these rebased versions of the same, or reverts? or something else? (Also, your expected result is impossible since `D` will always have `C` for its parent, no matter what)

Comment: @RomainValeri `C` is the parent of `C'` (also parent of `D`).  Your point about `D` always needing to have `C` as its parent makes sense.  So, perhaps I would need to replace `D` with some `D''` in the diagram, that is the same as `D` except that it has `C'` as its parent?

Comment: You did not answer my question. Of course `C` is `C'`'s parent, your schema already told us that. I'll rephrase : why did you NOT name all your commits with different letters if they're all just commits. We often use `A'` to mean the rebased version of `A` or the reversion of `A`.

Comment: @RomainValeri Sorry, I had misunderstood your question.  There is no relation between `D` and `D'`, `E` and `E'` etc.  (Only `C` is `C'`'s parent.)  My commit labels are confusing and I was not aware of the convention about rebased commits.

Comment: No offense, it was just to help you avoid creating false assumptions on answerers. I'd suggest renaming your schema if you feel like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer, for your new diagram, is you rebase off `G` with:

```
git checkout master
git rebase <commit_id_G>
```

The longer answer is that you're having difficulty seeing this because you're thinking of `master` as the "main" branch, and thinking of `dev` as the "offshoot". But, of course, these branch names are just labels, and you can consider either of them as the "main" branch.

And, since `master` is the branch we actually want to change, we can redraw the diagram like this:

```
          H---I---J        (master)
         / 
A---B---C---D---E---F---G  (dev)
```

with the associated expected result :

```
              H'--I'--J'    (master)
             / 
A---B---C---D---E---F---G   (dev)
```

Hopefully it's easier to see here, that we simply need to rebase `master` off this new `D` instead of `C`.

Comment: That should be `git rebase hash-of-D` (not hash of G) but otherwise this is right (and upvoted). Note that the original `H-I-J` chain remains in the repository (found temporarily via `ORIG_HEAD` and for at least 30 days by default through the reflog for `master`). I like to draw the new commits with names `H'-I'-J'` to denote that although we are using them *as if* they were the original `H-I-J` chain, they are in fact new commits with new, different hash IDs.

Comment: @torek I was referring to the G in the second diagram for the OP. It is a bit confusing right enough. I'll redo my second diagram with primes as you suggest though.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like my understanding of rebase was complete incorrect.  Would anyone be able to kindly introduce a good tutorial on git? 
(I've mostly been using git for version control on a single branch, kind of a replacement of svn, but I know there are many more things you can do with git and would be interestead to learn them.)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to rebase `master` onto `G`:

```
git checkout master
git rebase <id-of-G>
```

That will rewrite all the commits found in `master` which aren't found in `G` on top of `G`. There's no need for cherry-picking. Your `dev` branch will be unchanged.

Answer (score -2):

You would need to do the following:

Take not of the hash-refs of these commits: `C`, `C'`, `D`, `E`, `F`. Then:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git reset --hard C`
3. `git cherry-pick C'`
4. `git checkout dev`
5. `git rebase -i master` (interactive rebase to get rid of C')
6. `git checkout master`
7. `git cherry-pick D`
8. `git cherry-pick E`
9. `git cherry-pick F`

Push both branches with `--force` to finish.

I do not recommend this if you're not comfortable with `git` but that's how I would go about it if absolutely needed to do it like that.

You can always go this route

```
                           D'---E'---F'     (dev)
                          / 
A---B---C---D---E---F---C'  (master)
```

and just `cherry-pick C'` then rebase your `dev` branch against `master`. That would be the simplest solution.

Comment: This is a convoluted way to do it and will rewrite history on `dev` for no reason.

Comment: @CalumHalpin From the original post, he wants to rewrite history on both branches. he wants to take something from `dev`, put it in the middle of `master` then rebase `dev` out of the commit that was put in `master`.

Comment: His diagram showed exactly the same history for `dev`. It branched off `master` at a different point but that was because `master` had changed.

Comment: "I would like to pull `C'` into the `master` branch and change the branching point to `C'`". His original diagram shows this clearly. Not sure why everyone is just ignoring the original question here. As I said, I wouldn't do this personally but I'm sure he must have a reason to do this.

Comment: The "branching point" is just the point at which the history of the two branches diverges. Rebasing `master` alone onto `C'`/`G` changes it because now master also contains that commit. Either way the history of `dev` will be `A -> B -> C -> G -> H -> I -> J`, there's no need to rebase/rewrite those commits. That's why we're "ignoring" that part of the original question.